# jquery mobile loading a ajax result within a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a small app using jquery mobile. I have the following scenario

- The user hits the URL and comes to the home page
- There are multiple div elements with data-role="page". The home page id is "home". There is a search button on the home page. When the user enters something and clicks on search, I am retrieving some data via Ajax.
- The data should be populated in a div with data-role="page" and id="Search".

So, my question here what is the best way to populate the result in the div? In normal jquery, I would just do $("#Search").html("data received via ajax");

Is there any jquery mobile standard to use here? Or should I use a different page for the results? Please help me in choosing the best way

Comment: I am getting json formatted data.

Comment: Never mind. As of now I am using changePage method. Let me know if this can be done in any better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is coming back as JSON, the best way for you to go is probably to use [jsRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html).  It is the stated direction by the jquery team for client side templating. It's also very easy and powerful.

I have [an example](http://roughlybrilliant.com/examples/example_using_jsrender_and_json_apis_in_jquery_mobile.php) on my tech blog where I use JSON APIs from Flickr and dynamically generate pages to transition to.  The example also has some commented out options in the code that you might find useful for DOM size management.

Comment: @sliger. What I am doing right now is, I am using changePage('searchResults.php'.....). In searchResults.php, I am doing the looping of query results in a normal way, and it works fine. No need of JSON and all. Which is the best way? I am not using any external APIs.

Comment: Actually, if you're just going to be rendering the HTML on the server (which is probably a better policy anyway) you don't even have to use the changePage method. Just create a normal HTML form and return standard jquerymobile page markup and you're set. No custom coding required. Is your project anywhere I can see it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading over the jQM Documentation

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/index.html

Particularly

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html